# Fatal error when restoring backup wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

i change hosting for my site and now the old server is down, i done the backup from ftp and mysql. I change the config.php but it gave error with some file in the include folder (missing). I check the backup and i think is missing the entire wp-includes folder.
So i downloaded the same version of wordpress (4.0) and uploaded in FTP but now the error is

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class WP_MatchesMapRegex in
>   /data/vhosts/murarolightstand.com/prova.murarolightstand.com/wp-includes/class-wp.php
>   on line 633

It's old version of wordpress and and old avada theme. There is nothing can i do to restore the site ? If i've the wp-admin and wp-content and the database it's possible to restore in some way ?
I'm in your hands

Answer (score 0):

If you have entire backup of your previous WordPress site and database.
upload new WordPress and replace wp-content of its with new one.

try checking it if you still that error come.
rename themes and plugin directory inside wp-content.
and also rename you current theme directory i.e Avada

after that admin panel will be accessible to you.
now replace your theme and plugin directory name to actual and 
reset permalink from Adminpanel=>settings=>permalink=>pretty permalink=

Comment: Sorry for my English, the problem is the old hosting has closed the server so i can't anymore create new backup copies. I only have this one but it's missing the wp-includes folder.

Comment: Do you have backup of your previous wp-content folder or not ?

Comment: Yes and wp-admin

Comment: your site is just inside wp-content folder
rest of the setup is of WordPress own.

so what's the problem now?  you can replace you any current version of WordPress setup wp-content by your old one.

Comment: I'm trying now, but if the original wordpress installation was a 4.0 and the new installation is the current version, it's not a problem ?

Comment: If your development done in better way inside you theme and plugins 
then it will not give any problem.

if it will give then we will use wp 4.0 itself.
first check with latest version.

Comment: If your previous developer used any deprecated code then it may give problem.
but later on we will do this with wp 4.0..... No Problem

Comment: With the latest version it gave me this error
Warning: include_once(/data/vhosts/murarolightstand.com/prova.murarolightstand.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/framework/plugins/multiple_sidebars.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /data/vhosts/murarolightstand.com/prova.murarolightstand.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/functions.php on line 25



Now i try with the 4.0 version

Comment: What happen with 4.0 version then ?

Comment: Ok with the 4.0 it works i can log but there is no page, post plugin everything. And when i try to activate avada theme it gave me this error

Warning: include_once(/data/vhosts/murarolightstand.com/prova.murarolightstand.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/framework/plugins/multiple_sidebars.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /data/vhosts/murarolightstand.com/prova.murarolightstand.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/functions.php on line 25    
And other error

Comment: the error is at function.php line 25. I can't help without checking it.
if any expert here please answer this.